# Invalid Field Count when uploading .csv file to a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, import, fileupload, data-import-wizard

ValidationErrors:

```
CaseSensitiveSalesforceID: 99
Required Field: 7
Invalid Field Count: 1
```

I'm trying to data load a .csv files, everything matches accordingly, trying to troubleshoot what this error means, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was having a column with contact ID as well as some non-nullable parameters that were affecting the upload. Marketing Cloud rejects the 15 digit SFID as a direct import in .csv.